# Создание админки с помощью /admin

Tags: python, aiogram

Сегодня использовал ранее метод, который мне подсказали тут. Возникла ошибка, теперь бот либо не видит канал, или вообще его не читает. Привожу код

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['admin'])
async def admin(message: types.Message):
    user_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=CHANNEL_ID, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    print(user_status)
    if isinstance(user_status, ChatMemberMember):
       await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы вошли основатель", reply_markup=nav.adminMenu)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы не администратор!")
```

Пишет что пользователь который создал чат, является member а не owner. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Что пишет в user_status?

Comment: Дайте точный текст принта

Comment: {"user": {"id": 1313793029, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Terl", "username": "Yuenemi", "language_code": "ru"}, "status": "member"}

Создателя распознаёт как member...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была связанна, с тем что я создал не то что бот может читать. То есть я создал группу, где он работал но не мог читать группу. Для использование ChatMemberMember, и определение роли нужно создавать канал.